# mpi_waitall in mpich2 with null values in array_of_requests

Tags: fortran, fortran90, mpich, pgi

I get the following error with MPICH-2.1.5 and PGI compiler;

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Waitall: Invalid MPI_Request, error stack:
PMPI_Waitall(311): MPI_Waitall(count=4, req_array=0x2ca0ae0, status_array=0x2c8d220) failed
PMPI_Waitall(288): The supplied request in array element 0 was invalid (kind=0)
```

in the following example Fortran code for a stencil based algorithm,

```
Subroutine data_exchange

! data declaration

integer request(2*neighbor),status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,2*neighbor)
integer n(neighbor),iflag(neighbor)
integer itag(neighbor),neigh(neighbor)

! Data initialization
request = 0; n = 0; iflag = 0;

! Create data buffers to send and recv
! Define values of n,iflag,itag,neigh based on boundary values

! Isend/Irecv look like this
ir=0
do i=1,neighbor
   if(iflag(i).eq.1) then
      ir=ir+1
      call MPI_Isend(buf_send(i),n(i),MPI_REAL,neigh(i),itag(i),MPI_COMM_WORLD,request(ir),ierr)
      ir=ir+1
      call MPI_Irecv(buf_recv(i),nsize,MPI_REAL,neigh(i),MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,request(ir),ierr)
   endif
enddo

! Calculations

call MPI_Waitall(2*neighbor,request,status,ierr)

end subroutine
```

The error occurs when the `array_of_request` in mpi_waitall gets a null value (`request(i)=0`). The null value in `array_of_request` comes up when the conditional `iflag(i)=1` is not satisfied. The straight forward solution is to comment out the conditional but then that would introduce overheads of sending and receiving messages of 0 sizes which is not feasible for large scale systems (1000s of cores).

As per the [MPI-forum link](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node49.html), the `array_of_requests` list may contain null or inactive handles.

I have tried following,

1. not initializing `array_of_requests`,
2. resizing `array_of_request` to match the `MPI_isend + MPI_irecv` count,
3. assigning dummy values to `array_of_request`
4. I also tested the very same code with MPICH-1 as wells as OpenMPI 1.4 and the code works without any issue.

Any insights would be really appreciated!

Comment: This might be related (though not exactly the same issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441163/mpi-waitall-is-failing

Comment: Null handles in MPI are named constants, e.g. `MPI_PROC_NULL`, `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`, etc. Their values are implementation specific and in most cases are not `0`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just move the first increment of `ir` into the conditional as well. Then you would have all handles in `request(1:ir)` at the and of the loop and issue:

```
call MPI_Waitall(ir,request(1:ir),status(:,1:ir),ierr)
```

This would make sure all requests are initialized properly.

Another thing: does `n(i)` in `MPI_Isend` hold the same value as `nsize` in the corresponding `MPI_Irecv`?

EDIT:
After consulting the MPI Standard (3.0, Ch. 3.7.3) I think you need to initialize the request array to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` if you want give the whole request array to `MPI_Waitall`.

Comment: After moving ir into the conditional and changing the COUNT in mpi_waitall call, the problem is resolved. The issue still remains as to why MPICH2 does not like null in the array_of_requests. The n(i) and nsize do hold the same value.

Comment: My guess would be that MPICH2 does not initialize the request array for you any more.

Comment: `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` is equal to `738197504` in Intel MPI, which derives from MPICH2, therefore I would assume that in MPICH2 it is also a non-zero constant.